# Could not start application returned a bad value: {Phoenix.PubSub, [name: AppName.PubSub, adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]}

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to elixir and trying setup my application but while staring the server facing the issue

`** (Mix) Could not start application AppName: AppName.Application.start(:normal, []) returned a bad value: {Phoenix.PubSub, [name: AppName.PubSub, adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]}`

I have upgrade packages ie
phoenix from 1.4.6 to 1.5.9
phoenix_pubsub from 1.1 to 2.0

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really the place for troubleshooting your specific problem, try asking on the Elixir Forums instead: https://elixirforum.com/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chrismccord/e53e79ef8b34adf5d8122a47db44d22f#pubsub-20-changes

Answer (score 0):

The default adapeter for Phoenix is PG2, what is your configuration inside application.exs